# Ask for login before sending a post request (submit a form) spring security

Tags: javascript, jquery, spring-boot, spring-security

I have a form in my website for sending a rate which is accessible by everyone.

So before submitting the form, a popup is opened asking for login.

There are two cases:

- A rate is sent anonymously without authentication or
- the user login before sending the rate.

My question is :

How can I still on the same page and conserve the selected data after the login process and then send the rate.

Thank you.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can you `AJAX` for this.

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6960586/11921403) is how you can post the form through AJAX using jQuery.

Comment: This could have been posted as a comment since it doesn't add any new information from the linked SO answer.

Comment: The pb is that there is the spring security. In the second case, I have two forms to submit. The login form and the form for sending the rate

Comment: @alia When you have to submit 2 forms, you first send an AJAX request for the login and on the success callback of that, you can send the rate form through AJAX again